# EWS --> Get Email Signautre of User (from outlook Exchange server)

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

i'm using PHP-ews library to connect to our Outlook Exchange Server (via OWA) to view/send/delete Emails (in a PHP-Email Web-Application).

The only thing i can't figure out is, how to get the Email-Signature (of a logged-in user), which i require when writing new Mails.

Has anyone experiencewith (PHP-)EWS?

Every Help is appreciated